# Google Data Studio / Looker Studio : scorecard comparing vs prior month based on a filter

Tags: looker-studio

****1)** Data** I have a following dataset in google sheets [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CNEan-vgFMoJVHXFfImBWxi9uU41lkM4QUNZ933aQ_g/edit?usp=sharing). In the sheets sample I have only 4 months of data but normally there would be many, many more to come in the future.

| MONTH | DATE | KATEGORIE | DOWNTIME | TIME (min) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 01/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 50 |
| 9 | 02/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 65 |
| 9 | 03/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 91 |
| 9 | 04/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 52 |
| 9 | 05/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 72 |
| 9 | 06/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 44 |
| 9 | 07/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 55 |
| 9 | 08/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 30 |
| 9 | 09/09/2021 | 01 DURCHLAUF | 0 | 42 |

**2) Expected output table and desired output**

I want to create a scorecard for *02 Downtime* to show total time for a given month.

If I filter for November, I would like the scorecard to compare vs October. (abs=1180, %=45)
Similarly, if I select December, I want to see the amount vs November (abs=940, %=25)

As a safety measure, if someone selects 2 months simultaneously, then perhaps it should not show any comparison. (unless it's possible to even do 2 vs 2 months, but it's not a necessity.)

**3) Chart: Configuration + Setup**

I have created a simple scorecard and a pivot table. I filtered out only Downtime.

**4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output and 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4.**

In my file [link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/871ff5a1-2d77-4616-8ced-b4398be429e5) you see the mentioned scorecard but I fail to include any comparison that is kind of "dynamic" that changes the month in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added solution to your dashboard [page 2](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/871ff5a1-2d77-4616-8ced-b4398be429e5/page/p_4ob7p8ov0c)

- Cross join the datasource with itself
- use the following calculated fields for expected output.

Daet01:

`CAST(CONCAT(DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE123),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE123),01)) AS DATE)`

Previous Month:

`TIME (min) (Table 1)-CASE WHEN Daet01 (Table 2) = DATETIME_SUB(Daet01 (Table 1), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN  TIME (min) (Table 2) ELSE 0 END`

% Difference:

`(TIME (min) (Table 1)-CASE WHEN Daet01 (Table 2) = DATETIME_SUB(Daet01 (Table 1), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN  TIME (min) (Table 2) ELSE 0 END)/TIME (min) (Table 2)`

-

[image]

Comment: Hey, I click the filter on page2 but nothing changes on the scorecard below... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you recheck now...